# How do I create an alert based on the last page visited?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to mimic the 'dashboard' of https://finance.cs50.net/ (once you've logged in), which displays a 'bought' alert if you are redirected there from /buy, but no alert if you end up there otherwise.

I'm using Flask, jinja2, python, and HTML. The address provided is ("/"), which works fine with `return redirect`, but not with `return render_template`. I tried passing in a flag with `return redirect`, but my computer didn't like that. You always know the UserId, but navigation is not being tracked (i.e. no cookies). Simple answers that I can understand are preferred to clever ones that I cannot.

```
# from application.py, at the end of the 'buy' function

# flag says local to 'buy' so this does not help me
flag = True
return redirect("/")

## also tried, but computer got angry
return render_template("/")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know how the alert looks like but it sounds like you might be looking for `flash`. The documentation is available [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/flashing/#simple-flashing)

Also using the example provided in the documentation, the handler for '/buy' should look like `buy()` below:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, \
     request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'some_secret'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/buy', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def buy():
    if False:
        pass
    else:
        flash('You were redirected from /buy')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('buy.html')
```